# What C++ compiler to target both Linux and Windows?

Tags: c++, cross-platform

I would like to make a simple database-like software. It will work like MySQL/PostgreSQL but it will be very, very simple and different. It should work on both Windows and Linux (just like MySQL/PostgreSQL do). I want to do that in C++.

Is there a compiler I can use to write one code, and then compile that code to both platforms? Of course these could be two different compilers, each compiling for one platform.

To answer one of the questions below - yes it's clear to me that I can't have one binary for both platforms. I want to use one code and get two different binaries as a result using probably 2 different compilers.

Comment: You can use gcc on Linux and then gcc with either MingW or cygwin on Windows.

Comment: little confusion there.. first you ask about same compiler then you say different code.. for common code there's boost, gtk, qt (among other things).

Comment: It is actually best to have your code compile on many compilers to check if it is really portable. Choosing only one will bite you later.

Comment: What I mean is to write one code, and compile it for two platforms. I can compile it twice, each on every platform. Question is what compiler(s?) can I use to achieve that. OR (if it's not possible) - do I have to use different code for both platforms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compile on windows using MinGW for Windows and gcc on Linux: MinGW is a minimalist implementation of gcc for windows. It's "the same compiler", however it's wont produce the same binary, because one is for windows, the other for linux.

It's better to write portable and standard code, so that you do not rely on any particular compiler. This way, it will compile under most platform and compilers. Boost, Qt, Ace are some example cross-platform libraries that you could use.

Answer (score 2):

You can not produce an executable from one compiler[1] that works in both Windows and Linux - it's just not possible to achieve that.

It's not a question of compilers, it's a question of "what happens after the compiler is done".

It is certainly possible to write code that compiles and works on both Linux and Windows, but you have to build two different executable files (possibly more if you want to support 64- and 32-bit flavours of the OS's, and of course if you want to run on ARM or PowerPC, etc, that would also require a separate build.

[1] Before someone else points it out: it's possible to build a compiler that can produce two binaries - yes, this is theoretically possible.

Comment: you can produce 2 different binaries with one compiler and one codebase. Compilers genally do not produce code ;)

Comment: @SebastianLange: Actually, I think producing (machine) code is exactly what compilers do. But I have replaced the word with executable.

Comment: I am ok with calling it machine code, i maybe just read code as source code ;)

Comment: As far as I know Googles NaCl build both ARM and x86 code in 1 binary

Comment: I don't need to use one compiler, I can use both, each for every platform. Question is what compilers I can use, to compile THE SAME code, without much trouble. There will be no GUI, generaly just disk write/read and socket communication. So I think it should be possible.

Comment: As long as the compiler is standards compliant, and your code follows the standard, shouldn't be a problem. But you can of course get variants for gcc for most platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `cmake` for cross-compilation with one compiler. For Frameworks there is boost and QT, depending your needs. But to run your software on both systems you are not neccesarily bound to boost or QT or cmake, it just makes it easier in a lot of cases, but strict c++ os-independent code can do the job too. For OS-specific parts you can still use preprocessor directives. Compilation can be done in different compilers too (GCC at linux, MSVC at windows).

Answer (score 1):

When I was writing a cross-platform game before, I maintained the development on Linux but I frequently switched to windows(VS2010, VC++) to see if there is a problem. Do not trust standard codes that much because some compilers, VC++ for example, do not support all standards.